# Azure Video Analyzer for Media: Celebrity description language

Tags: azure-video-indexer

We're experimenting with Azure Video Analyzer for Media. I've uploaded some video clips, specifying the language as Norwegian (nb-NO). But in the celebrity detection pane, when I view the celebrity description, the language can in some cases be French, in others Turkish, English, or Norwegian. What governs the language choice for the celebrity descriptions? Is there some parameter I can set? When viewing the results for one particular clip, if I choose Translation: Norwegian, I get the description in Turkish. If I choose Translation: Swedish, it's in English. This problem exists whether we're using the portal or going via the API (using widgets to display the results).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention.
The celebrity description language should be identical to the selected language you indexed with / translated to if we support the language.

You mentioned above several use cases that I'd like to ensure I understand.
What is the video source language? what language did you translate to? and what was the actual description language. If possible, include the video id

Comment: Thanks for replying! One example is video id 9917029fc6. The source language was set to nb-NO when uploading the video. When I view the celebrity description for Kåre Willoch, I get it in (what I believe to be) Turkish. If I switch the Translation (in the GUI) to Swedish, I get it in English. And if I select one of the other identified celebs in the same video, Gro Harlem Brundtland, the description is in Spanish.

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to reproduce this? Also, I should probably mention that we're using the West Europe DC, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you with this, but we are eager to proceed with Video Analyzer, primarily using the API, and this is a show-stopper for us. Any developments? Anyone else experiencing the same issue?